# ajax reads Json file before update in a Live search

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

I am writing a live search using jquery Ajax that posts a keyword to php file that writes the result in a JSON file then I read this JSON file as a search result.
my problem is Jquery GET from JSON is always retrieve the previous search result

script file

```
$("#searchArea").keyup(function() {
var searchKeyword = $(this).val();
        if (searchKeyword.length > 0) {
            $.post('livesearch.php', { keywords: searchKeyword });
            $.getJSON('livesearch.json',function(data){
                var resultBox = $('#searchReasult');
                 var output = '<ul>';
                $.each(data, function(key, val){
                output +=  '<li>';
                output += '<h3>' + val.username + '</h3>';
                output += '</li>';
                })
                output += '</ul>';
                $('#update').html(output);
               console.log(output)
               if(searchKeyword.length=0){$('#update').hide;}
            })
                    }
if(searchKeyword.length=0){$('#update').hide;}
```

PHP file

```
<?php
require_once('includes/database.php');
require_once('includes/USER.php');
$key = (isset($_POST['keywords']))? $_POST['keywords']:null;
if(isset($key)){
    global $database;
    $esc_key = $database->escape_value($key);
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM user ";
    $sql .= "WHERE username LIKE '%$esc_key%' OR ";
    $sql .= " first_name LIKE '%$esc_key%' OR ";
    $sql .= " last_name LIKE '%$esc_key%' ";
    $sql .= "LIMIT 10 ";
    $result = USER::find_by_sql($sql);
    foreach($result as $user){
        $user->password = null;
    }    
    $fp = fopen('livesearch.json', 'w');
    fwrite($fp, json_encode($result));
    fclose($fp);

}?>
```

Comment: Several syntax errors. `if(searchKeyword.length=0)` should use `===` and `hide` is a function

Comment: Why are there 2 ajax calls? Note they will be done virtually simultaneously which might be your problem. Whole approach doesn't make much sense. Would be simpler to use one php script to return what is needed instead of writing to json file

Comment: it works now thank you